# How can I resolve this error while installing scrapy package?

Tags: python, scrapy, anaconda, conda, conda-forge

In Anaconda2,

I'm trying to install `scrapy 1.8.0 py-27` using Conda.

When I run:
`Conda install scrapy`

The following error occurs:

> ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions<337>: An error occurred while installing package
>   'conda-forge::pkginfo-1.5.0.1-py_0'
>
> CondaError: Cannot link a source that doesn't exist.
>   C:\Anaconda2\Scripts\conda.exe
>
> Running 'conda clean --packages' may resolve your problem.

Comment: You have been reading and following the error message?

Comment: I couldn't follow the error message as I'm just a beginner in Python.

Comment: 2) After looking up so much on the internet, I finally uninstalled it and installed latest Anaconda version. 3) Subsequently, I was able to install scrapy normally using conda. 4) Currently, I'm facing issues with googlesearch package. I have installed it using - pip command but even then I am not able to import 'search' module. 5) Can you assist me in this concern?

Comment: @SherylHohman Sorry, couldn't present my question in the best structure in a hurry. Thanks for the edits.